# 404 after removing “category” base in wordpress

Tags: php

I have a permalink issue. I make a category events

My permalink setting is:

Custom url: /category/events/

Category Base: (.)

After this setting saved, my url should be

www.mydomain.com/events/

instead of

www.mydomain.com/category/events/
But it is showing 404 error.

Comment: are you using yoast seo plugin ?

Comment: No I am NOT USING ANY PLUGIN.